# Jhipster: How to enable multiple languages for existing monolithic project

Tags: java, jhipster

I've generated monolithic project without multiple languages. And for now, I want to enable multiple languages feature for the current project. How can I do this?

I tried command **yo jhipster:languages** but it thrown error **Translation is disabled for the project. Languages cannot be added.**

Comment: Edit your .yo-rc.json file to enable i18n and re-generate your project

Comment: It just add new language config files. I mean how can I update for existing old files that I want to show multiple languages on home page.

Comment: It seems you did not understand my proposition, I meant add `"enableTranslation": true,` line to your `.yo-rc.json` file and run `yo jhipster` again on your project. It'll change many files. Of course, make sure you have everything committed in git before doing so.

Comment: Cool, it worked. Thanks @Gaël Marziou